# Multilayered navbar dynamic population with php and sql - trouble with third layer

Tags: php, html, css, sql

Alright, so this is the problem. I have a navigation bar with 3 different layers. I am trying to use SQL and PHP to populate layer 2, and 3 dynamically from a database. Layer 1 is hardcoded.

Layer 1 is the visible options.
Layer 2 is what you get when hovering over layer 1.
Layer 3 is what you get when hovering over layer 2.

[Navbar - Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LLhv.png)

The last options in the photo are hardcoded in so I can show an example of how the menu should look. The options above the last three are from my attempts at getting the code to work.

**PHP section contained in the nav.php used to generate the menu option 'Rules'**

```
<li><a href="" <?= (strpos($url, 'rules') !== false) ? "class=\"navbar-active-selection\"" : ""; ?>>Rules</a>
     <ul>
         <?php
            // Establish the connection to the database
            include("connection.php"); //Establishing connection with our database

            // Setup the query
            $sql = "SELECT sub_categories.id AS sub_cat_id, sub_categories.link AS sub_cat_link, sub_categories.name AS sub_cat_name, sub_categories.nestUnder AS sub_cat_nestUnder, sub_category_links.id AS sub_cat_link_id, sub_category_links.link AS sub_cat_link_link, sub_category_links.name AS sub_cat_link_name, sub_category_links.nestUnder AS sub_cat_link_nestUnder FROM sub_categories inner join sub_category_links ON sub_categories.id = sub_category_links.nestUnder";
            $result = $db->query($sql);

            if($result->num_rows > 0)
            {
                // This creates the first part fine...
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                {
                    echo "<li><a href=\"" . $row['sub_cat_link'] ."\">" .$row['sub_cat_name'] ."</a>";

                   // This is where the code to populate the third layer should go
                   // but I am not skilled enough to figure it out.

                   echo "</li>";
                }
            }
       ?>
   </ul>
</li>
```

**My databases look like this...**

```
Table categories (Layer 1)
  id int (Primary, Auto increment)
  link varchar
  name varchar

Table sub_categories (Layer 2)
  id int (Primary, Auto increment)
  link varchar
  name varchar
  nestUnder int

Table sub_category_links (Layer 3)
  id int (Primary, Auto increment)
  link varchar
  name varchar
  nestUnder int
```

The nestUnder part of each table links to the id of the table above it.

Example: sub_categories nestUnder links to categories id.

Example: sub_category_links nestUnder linkes to sub_categories id.

I am not an expert on this stuff, I have limited knowledge as I am learning it in college right now, and using google, a friend, and trial and error to fill in the blanks.

If there is anything else you need provided, or any questions you may have, please feel free to ask.

Comment: Just basically repeat the query you have now, just change it to use the layer 3 table, and match it against layer 2 table, and check for numrows, like you do with the sub_cat one you have now. Put it where you need it, so it populates based on the current ID for layer 2?

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie I am not really sure how to actualize that into code. I gave it a few shots and I am having issues with it. Would you be able to provide an example of what you mean please?